# Generic class to get add/remove event of a Collection

Tags: c#, collections, encapsulation

1. What do you people think about this solution to encapsulate a collection and be able to know when an iten is added/removed.
2. How can I add a clicable link to the xml description?

   ```
   // Why does DoNotExposeGenericLists recommend that I expose Collection instead of List? by David Kean"
   // http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2006/04/27/585476.aspx
   public class CollectionEx<T> : Collection<T>
   {
   public event EventHandler ItemAdded;
   public event EventHandler ItemRemoved;

   public CollectionEx()//:base()
   {
   }

   protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
   {
       base.InsertItem(index, item);
       OnSectionAdded(EventArgs.Empty);
   }

   protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
   {
       base.RemoveItem(index);
       OnSectionRemoved(EventArgs.Empty);
   }

   public new void Add(T item)
   {
       base.Add(item);
       OnSectionAdded(EventArgs.Empty);
   }
   public new bool Remove(T item)
   {
       bool ok = base.Remove(item);
       OnSectionRemoved(EventArgs.Empty);
       return ok;
   }

   protected override void ClearItems()
   {
       base.ClearItems();
   }

   protected virtual void OnSectionRemoved(EventArgs e)
   {
       EventHandler handler = this.ItemRemoved;
       if (handler != null)
       {
           handler(this, e);
       }
   }

   protected virtual void OnSectionAdded(EventArgs e)
   {
       EventHandler handler = this.ItemAdded;
       if (handler != null)
       {
           handler(this, e);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: I think you just re-invented ObservableCollections.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms668604.aspx) for this purpose. No need to write it yourself.

Besides: When subclassing `Collection<T>` it's enough to override the protected virtual methods. All other public methods will invoke them.
If you additionally hide the non-virtual ones the way you did, events might be triggered multiple times (and in your case, when clearing the collection, no event will be triggered).

Comment: owwwww! I didnt know that class! Sorry! Well, the blog guy didn't know either! :P. Thanks a lot!!! And thanks to clarify the virtual/public mess that I did.

Comment: I think at the time the blog post was made (Apr 2006), there was no `ObservableCollection` - it was released together with .NET 3.0 (Nov 2006) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this exists already, have a look at the `ObservableCollection<T>.`

Answer (score 1):

There is an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) shipped with .NET 4.0. The `CollectionChanged` event delivers details information on what has been modified, added or deleted.

Comment: `ObservableCollection<T>` was there since .NET 3.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx